# Javascript/JQuery if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

This is probably pretty simple, but I can't figure out how to do it:
I have this code:

```
$.post("/admin/contract", {
                          'mark_paid' : true,
                          'id' : id
        },
```

In pseudo code, how can I do this:

```
$.post("/admin/contract", {
                          'mark_paid' : true,
                          'id' : id,
                          if(is_set(dont_email)) {print 'dont_email' : true}
        },
```

Comment: What is `dont_email` and how is `is_set` defined?

Comment: I think he's using the php function `is_set` to show what he wants in pseudocode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How I'd do it.

```
$.post("/admin/contract", {
  'mark_paid' : true,
  'id' : id,
  'dont_email' : ( 'undefined' != typeof dont_email )
},
```

Comment: Is what I was going to write.  The cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give it a try :

```
$.post("/admin/contract", {
                          'mark_paid' : true,
                          'id' : id,
                          'dont_email' : is_set(dont_email) ? true : undefined
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var details = {
    'mark_paid' : true,
    'id' : id,
}

if(is_set(dont_email)) {
    details.dont_email = true;
}

$.post("/admin/contract", details);
```

untested...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.post("/admin/contract", {
                 'mark_paid' : true,
                 'id' : id,
                 'dont_email': (is_set(dont_email))?true:false
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Is dont_email a variable? Are you checking the existence of dont_email?

```
var myDontEmail = (typeof(dont_email) != "undefined");

$.post("/admin/contract", {
             'mark_paid' : true,
             'id' : id,
             'dont_email': myDontEmail
        },
```